# Can minerals form in the subsurface?

Tags: minerals

Can gypsum form in the subsurface? If there is another source of sulfate and maybe limestone dissolution happening, if the ionic strength is high enough can gypsum crystals form in groundwater?

Comment: yes, gypsum can form from solution in the ground. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gypsum